# get the position of a value in a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I get the position of a given value inside a table column. I need to get the column number.

Comment: Are you saying you know which row, but not which column contains the value?...  Doesn't seem like sound relational design, if I understand correctly.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Columns do not have numbers in relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

In psuedo-code:

- For each through the column column collection in the result set.
- When you find the value, note the index number

This assumes one row only.

You can't do this in T-SQL: only a client language such as .net or Java

Answer (score 0):

One option is to query the ColID column from syscolumns for your table [ `select [name],[colid] from dbo.syscolumns where [id] = object_id('tablename')` ]. Note that I'm not sure if this is guaranteed to be sequential or if gaps could appear if a column is dropped.